# after doing getExtra from intent how do i display it in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

im a noob so please give detailed answers:)

This is the class for get extra wherein i want to display the string

```
package kfc.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class productdetail extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.productdetail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    }




}
```

This is where i want the string to be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top|center"
  android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"      
                android:background="@drawable/button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="ADD TO MENU" android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="4sp" android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:background="@drawable/button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="GET TOTAL" android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="15sp" android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Serving Size: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>
          <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

    </TableLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left">

    </TableRow>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Amount Per Serving: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calories:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="% Daily Value:          "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="35"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="60"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Saturated Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="34"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Trans Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="53"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cholesterol:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sodium:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView26"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Carbohydrate:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="200"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Dietary Fiber:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView28"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="34"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Sugars:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView29"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="16"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Protein:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vitamin A: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="   Vitamin C: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calcium: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="35"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="   Iron: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

thank you your answers will be much appreciated

Comment: when you get the string , where do you want to display it ??!

Comment: You want to display the string in one of your textview. Is that u meant?

Comment: What exact requirement of your is not mentioned in question. Try to give full detail of what you want to do then you will get the exact and quick response .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display arraylist class in a list view with a parameter of the arraylist class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322968/how-to-display-arraylist-class-in-a-list-view-with-a-parameter-of-the-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you want it to be displayed, you will need to do this at runtime.

```
//Assign textview and call it tv
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");

//set tv text to str
tv.setText(str);
```

Hope that helps